# Sort Based on multiple field value Js

Tags: javascript, sorting

Let's say I have this array of object :

```
var data = [
  {id:1, check:true, citizen: true},
  {id:2, check:true, citizen: ''},
  {id:3, check:'', citizen: true},
  {id:4, check:'', citizen: ''},
  {id:5, check:true, citizen: true},
]
```

I want to display those items with **check** and **citizen** true then items with check true and then items with citizen true and items without citizen and check (empty ones) should come last.

I have tried this but seems that should be handled in different way.

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var Acheck = a.check
        var Acitizen = a.citizen

        var Bcheck = b.check
        var Bcitizen = b.citizen
        return (Acheck === Bcheck) ? 0 : Acitizen ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track? Just write out the logic in your comparator first, then start tightening it up with ternaries etc. Be as verbose as necessary because the order of operations is (1) make it work (2) make it better, not (1) make it concise (2) figure out why it doesn't work =)

Comment: can you help me with that ? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you need to go through each of your conditions and write them out in order of priority, so test `a` against `check && citizen`, `check`, `citizen` and then return the appropriate result based on `b`'s `check` and `citizen` values. I've done that below. You could potentially optimise the logic (e.g. using ternary operators inside the outer `if/else` block), but you would have to factor in the loss of readability of the code.

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, check:true, citizen: true},
  {id:4, check:'', citizen: ''},
  {id:2, check:true, citizen: ''},
  {id:3, check:'', citizen: true},
  {id:5, check:true, citizen: true},
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.check && a.citizen) {
    return (!b.check || !b.citizen) ? -1 : 0;
  } 
  else if (a.check) {
    if (b.check) {
      return b.citizen ? 1 : 0;
    } 
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  else if (a.citizen) {
    if (b.citizen) {
      return b.check ? 1 : 0;
    } 
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  } 
  else {
    return b.check || b.citizen ? 1 : 0;
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var Acheck = a.check === true;
        var Acitizen = a.citizen === true;

        var Bcheck = b.check === true;
        var Bcitizen = b.citizen === true;
        
        // handle case when both have check: true
        if(Acheck && Bcheck){
            // handle case when both have check: true, citizen: true (both are equal)
            if(Acitizen && Bcitizen){
                return 0;
            }

            // if Acitizen = true, sort a before b
            return Acitizen ? -1 : (Bcitizen ? 0 : 1);
        }

        // if Acheck = true, sort a before b
        return Acheck ? -1 : 1;
});
```